# Create multiple range slide handles in one slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add multiple handles to a jQuery UI slider widget, as in 2 or 3 or more range sliders in one slider.

I have tried searching on google and found an article that shows how to modify it to have multiple handles but I need them to work as range sliders.

Is there anyway to make this work?

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1439,
    values: [540, 1020],
    animate: true,
    slide: slideTime
});
```

Thanks

Comment: "2 or 3 or more range sliders in one slider" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: i meant, multiple range handles in one slider

Comment: If you need more than two handles to select a range, you may consider having more than one slider. I can't even imagine how such a widget would be used... more than one range in a single slider?

Comment: i think you can use the class while using the id ..   $(".slider-range")

Comment: @Hameed: What Zack meant was, that he can't imagine a scenario where one slider with multiple ranges in it would make sense. The problem is that multiple ranges in one slider may overlap and it may not be clear which range belongs to which parameters.

Comment: @maenu, Imagine a working day time of a gym, like 6am-1pm 3pm-11pm... it would be amazing have a widget which could handle this. With 4 handles, i.e. ... btw srry my bad english.. if there is any doubt just tell me..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [colResizable jQuery](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples) plugin. It allows you to resize table columns and also to create multiple range sliders:

Comment: As of August 2014, is this still the best tool for the job?

Comment: Whether it's the best tool or not I guess is up for debate, though it does have changes made to it in the past two month according to the [github](https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable), so it has some active development still.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 23):

colResizable is fine and all, but if you're looking for something a bit more modern, I wrote [Elessar](http://quarterto-archive.github.io/Elessar) to fill this exact niche.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for sharing this mate! I'm going to use it this in a big project and hope to contribute to your repo soon.. thanks again!

Comment: Would it be easy enough to "link" ranges. As in, there are no gaps and when I resize one its sibling gets resized as well? (Like the colResizable demo)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Well, the "essential part of the answer" is "use Elessar". What else do you think I can include?

Comment: There is a nice fork called 'timetable': https://github.com/zerohun/Timetable . I like it for better event support like click and destroy.

Comment: @greener i've fixed the links, but note that i'm no longer maintaining Elessar

Comment: @KaraBrightwell I fully realize this is a shot in the dark, and that you're not maintaining this Elessar anymore, but do you happen to have any idea what might be blocking it from working with jQuery 3.0+? It seems to initially render fine, but then drag/resize/hover things don't work, and there are no console errors AND jQuery Migrate doesn't pick up on anything helpful.

Comment: @BRW, sorry, no idea, i haven't even used jQuery in a long time, i've no idea what could have broken it

Answer (score 5):

This is a wrapper that extends **jquery-ui slider** functionality and allows to build **multi-range slider** http://jsfiddle.net/ladrower/BmQq4/

It is easy to use. Just pass the selector of DOM element that will contain a multi-range slider.

```
<html>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</html>

<script>
    var intervals = new Intervals("#slider");
</script>
```

Please, check out the documentation and sources at GitHub https://github.com/ladrower/jquery-ui-intervals

Comment: Very cool addition Artem, but for better usability I think that the plus sign is not necessary and generates some confusion (too many controls in the bar). Just clicking an empty space should create a new range instead of modify a range that you are not pointing. I know that probably with little css and a few lines of js people can get this behavior, but not all people will do it. Anyway, great mod and thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I did edit.

You can look to http://jsfiddle.net/q5WEe/1/

I did edit line 70 to 82.

```
            /*edit
            if ( o.values.length && o.values.length !== 2 ) {
                o.values = [ o.values[0], o.values[0] ];
            }*/
        }
        /*edit
        this.range = $( "<div></div>" )
            .appendTo( this.element )
            .addClass( "ui-slider-range" +
            // note: this isn't the most fittingly semantic framework class for this element,
            // but worked best visually with a variety of themes
            " ui-widget-header" +
            ( ( o.range === "min" || o.range === "max" ) ? " ui-slider-range-" + o.range : "" ) );*/
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

colresizable wasn't right for me, as that was geared more towards tables, I really preferred to use the jquery UI widget, slider.
It looked like the source code could easily handle multiple handles, they just hadn't really built 'adding' or 'removing' handles live as a feature.
So I just added to the source code of jquery UI Slider (a bit scary...I know) but works pretty well.

```
var slider = $.widget("ui.slider", $.ui.mouse, {
    version: "1.11.4",
    widgetEventPrefix: "slide",
    //...
    value: function(newValue) {
        // ...
    },

    values: function(index, newValue) {
        // ...
    },

    //new function to allow creation of handles
    //you can add your own code to handle arguments or something for placing
    //the new handle in a specific spot
    addHandle: function() {
            //adds a new handle 
            this.options.values.push(this._trimAlignValue((this._valueMax() - this._valueMin()) / 2));
            this._refresh();
    },

    //new function to allow deleting handles
    //currently just takes the last value off, but you can make it fancier
    removeHandle: function() {
        //only remove a handle if there are more than 1 handles 
        if (this.options.values.length > 1) {
            this.options.values.pop();
            this._refresh();
        }
    },
   //...
 }
```

Then, when you want to call these functions, you do it like so

```
//when your 'add handle' button is clicked
$("#btn-add").click(function(){ 
    //call the add handle function you made within the slider widget
    $( "#slider" ).slider("addHandle"); 
});

$("#btn-remove").click(function(){
    $( "#slider" ).slider("removeHandle");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on jQuery UI, also [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) has this capability and is highly customizable.
It can't tell you the ranges rightaway, but you can get them easily from counting with handles, min and max like this:

```
//get array of connect elements (ranges)
var connect = multirange.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');

multirange.noUiSlider.on('update', function () {
 var valuesarr = multirange.noUiSlider.get(),
 max = multirange.noUiSlider.options.range.max[0],
 oldsum = multirange.noUiSlider.options.range.min[0];// = slider min, will be usually 0

 for ( var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++ ) {
     if(valuesarr[i]) $(connect[i]).text(valuesarr[i] - oldsum);
     else $(connect[i]).text(max - oldsum);
     oldsum=valuesarr[i];
 }
});
```

[see fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/5vhyyp37/3/)