# jquery slider with multiple handles (dynamically add and remove handles)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, uislider

What I want to achieve is to make it possible to the user to define as many ranges inbetween a start-value 0 and a max value, i.e. 1000. I thought about how to do this in the best way and I came up with either idea:

---

Either I could dynamically add and remove sliders on the fly to the page. Make the min-value of the first slider fixed to 0. And somehow link them, i.e. when changing the upper-value of the N-th slider, automatically adapt the lower-value of the (N+1)th slider and vice versa. Problem is that it's some hassle to get this working as I need to also adapt the previous slider (N-1) and next slider (N+1) when removing the slider N inbetween.

---

Then I thought of the following:

Have ONE slider with a fixed lower-value to 0 and with at least two handles, where the user can add and remove handles on the fly himself. There wouldn't be any gaps allowed, i.e. every pair of consecutive two handles would always define one range. Something like this:
jsfiddle.net/NkjQr/1781/ (this example would define two ranges) with fixed value at 0 and on the fly add/remove handles. Is this possible? Couldn't find any jquery plugin to do this easily...

Or do you know an even better solution? Im looking for the one which is the most easy to implement myself.
Thanks a lot

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368206/create-multiple-range-slide-handles-in-one-slider and related working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q5WEe/1/ as a start. ( no adding new ranges). Or another answer from same SO question, https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar (add ranges, but not directly connected. i.e. there can be gaps. but perhaps setting no-gap option is just an config option away)

Comment: unfortunately the single handles can overlap and it's not that easy to add/remove single handles :( But Ill try to figure it out, thanks so far.